# How to use dynamic paint with constrained objects

Tags: constraints, dynamic-paint

I need to apply dynamic paint to an object (say OB1) that is constrained to another (OB2)! The problem is that although OB1 is moving by changing OB2 location, its "real" position is fixed and thus, the waves do not appear (i.e. if I initialize OB1 location on my canvas plane the waves I want to achieve are in its fixed position). What am I doing wrong?

In the first image you can see that OB1 is attached to OB2 with a location contraint, but its location is (0,0,0). Note that OB1 is a brush, and a hole appears in location 0,0,0.

[image]

In the second image I displace OB2 and thus OB1. But nothing happens and the hole remains at location 0,0,0. As you can see "Plane" is the Canvas.

[image]

In this second image

I hope my explanation is clear :)

Comment: please provide screenshots and detailed explanation what you did...or your blend file

Comment: How can I attach the blend file?

Comment: You can use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/). Follow the instructions there. The file size limit is 30MB.