# Dynamic paint on uneven surface

Tags: dynamic-paint, shrinkwrap

I am trying to animate a ball rolling through a desert scene, leaving a trail behind it. The intention is for the ball to move along the surface of the plane rising and falling with its ridges.

In order to accomplish this I have attempted to use dynamic paint along with the shrink-wrap constraint.

When I attempt to make the ball follow a curve, dynamic paint does not appear to have any effect at all. When I add key frames, a trail is left that adheres to these but does not follow the shrink-wrapped path.

As a workaround is it possible to keyframe the shrink-wrap path?

Am I perhaps approaching this from the wrong direction? Please forgive my lack of blender prowess.

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

A similar unanswered query can be found here: [How to use dynamic paint with constrained objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223034/how-to-use-dynamic-paint-with-constrained-objects?newreg=366fb328d623455b8ef77eeb1b92920a)

.Blend:

[image]

Comment: So provide your blend file so we can check it out…

Comment: It's looks like the ball rolls in the air without touching the surface.

Comment: Apologies, I've added it now @Chris

Comment: thanks! Hint: if you include blend files in your question, you will get better and quicker answer...and the probability that someone is willing to help you increases ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select your plane, increase the substeps to 1 on your dynamic paint:

[image]

hit bake...and you get:

[image]

Comment: I had completely overlooked the bake button! Thanks so much for your help

Comment: You are welcome!